# How do I best take up carpet & remove glue from concrete floor

Tags: carpet

Would someone give a good list of the equipment, tools, supplies, etc., I would need to take up carpet and padding that is glued to the concrete floor.  Thank you.

Comment: What are you intending to do after the carpet is off?  The answer is likely going to be a lot different if you're replacing the carpet rather than, say, planning on staining the concrete.

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered previously several times. Here is the link: [carpet glued down removal.](https://diy.stackexchange.com/search?q=how%20to%20remove%20glued%20down%20carpet)